# What's the meaning of "to ha"?

Tags: word-meaning

> But when the Piper stepped ashore and not so much as a single squeak
>   was to be heard, the Mayor and the Council, and the town-folk
>   generally, began to hum and **to ha** and to shake their heads.

This is from an English (or Scottish) fairly tale "The Pied Piper". What's the meaning of "to ha"? could you teach me?

Comment: Compare "hem and haw".

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is "hum and ha" old form of ""hem and haw"?

Comment: It  has been around since at least the 15th century ("by humys and by hays") and is used in regional dialects as a variant of *hem and haw*.  These vocalizations express a hesitancy to act or a reluctance to say something outright.

Comment: *Hum/hem* and *ha/haw* are old ways of representing what contemporary US writers usually spell ‹um› and ‹uh› and contemporary British writers usually spell ‹er› and ‹erm›.

Comment: it's not ***to ha***: it's ***to hum and ha***, together. Same as: to hem and haw. Usually only one ***to*** is enough. I disagree with the comments about writers. To hem and haw and it's variants are verbs to express a number of interjections that point to not wanting to state something straight out.

Comment: But the interjections are not written different ways in BrE and AmE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**hum and ha**, **hem and haw** are vocalizations attested as early as the 15th century ("by humys and by hays", 1469, **hum**, [MED](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=82643477&egdisplay=open&egs=82644126)); they express a hesitancy to act or a reluctance to say something outright.